# AngularJS $filter('orderBy') strange sorting

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting, angularjs-filter, angularjs-orderby

Looks like AngularJS `$filter("orderBy")` works not the same way as `Array.prototype.sort`. 
I wrote example for this problem:

**Template:**

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div>arr1 angular </br>{{ arr1ang }}</div>
    <div>arr2 angular </br>{{ arr2ang }}</div>
    <div>arr1 js </br>{{ arr1js }}</div>
    <div>arr2 js </br>{{ arr2js }}</div>
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
angular.module('app', []);

function ctrl ($scope, $filter) {
    arr1 = [
      {value: "AA"}, 
      {value: "AB"}, 
      {value: "aa"}, 
      {value: "ab"}
    ];
    arr2 = [
      {value: "d"}, 
      {value: "D"}, 
      {value: "w"}, 
      {value: "e"}, 
      {value: "i"}, 
      {value: "O"}, 
      {value: "o"}, 
      {value: "r"}
    ];

    $scope.arr1ang = $filter('orderBy')(arr1, "value");
    $scope.arr2ang = $filter('orderBy')(arr2, "value");

    function comp(a,b){
        if (a.value > b.value)
            return 1;
        else if (b.value > a.value)
            return -1;
        else
            return 0;
    }

    arr1.sort(comp);
    arr2.sort(comp);
    $scope.arr1js = arr1;
    $scope.arr2js = arr2;
}

angular
  .module('app')
  .controller('ctrl', ctrl);
```

**Result:**

```
arr1 angular
[{"value":"AA"},{"value":"aa"},{"value":"AB"},{"value":"ab"}]
arr2 angular
[{"value":"d"},{"value":"D"},{"value":"e"},{"value":"i"},{"value":"O"},{"value":"o"},{"value":"r"},{"value":"w"}]
arr1 js
[{"value":"AA"},{"value":"AB"},{"value":"aa"},{"value":"ab"}]
arr2 js
[{"value":"D"},{"value":"O"},{"value":"d"},{"value":"e"},{"value":"i"},{"value":"o"},{"value":"r"},{"value":"w"}]
```

I made a Codepen example about it [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MapJwV?editors=101).

I don't understand something or it is a bug in AngularJS?

Comment: Please post code within the question itself. Questions should be self contained as links rot and we shouldn't have to go off site to review your problem. Adding demos is helpful as support for the code in the question.

Comment: @charlietfl Ok, just a second.

Comment: Array.sort works however you tell it to sort. Right now you are telling it to sort in a different way than how angular sorts.

Comment: @rob I just want to sort in the lexicographical order, like in dictionaries. Must AngularJS  sort by this may?

Comment: Why are you writing `</br>` instead of `<br>`? Where did you get that from?

Comment: @MrLister My bad, must use `<br />` instead. It is from XHTML standard.
Get it from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Angularjs orders it alphabetically case-insensitive. In JavaScript string comparison is case-sensitive.

One solution is to convert all values to lower-case or upper-case strings before comparison.

Comment: Well, this is definitely don't intuitive and even wasn't explained in documentation. Thanks for answer!

Comment: The `array.sort` method is explained pretty clearly here :https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: @SalientGreen I know about how JS string comparison works, I don't like the way of AngularJS sorting with hidden lower-casing.